# Where to place the .htaccess file on OpenShift for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, openshift-online-2

I would like to redirect to https and add this code to a .htaccess file for Drupal. Where should I place this file?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

on https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https it says web root.

UPDATE:

Found one .htaccess file in (see attached screenshot)
app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.43

[Drupal webroot on Openshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QexHL.png)

Comment: I'm not at a computer to check, but fairly sure the file should just be in the root of the GIT repo (I can't remember if that is the web root or if there is some application home directory).

Comment: The htaccess content also differs from the one on the page you linked to (which I've used in the past). I don't know if your htaccess file is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it in the web root, at the base of your site.

If your site is in `/var/www/mysite.com/public`, then the file would go in `/var/www/mysite.com/public/.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I can't find any var/www folder on Openshift. I've attached a link that shows some of the folders. I tried placing the .htaccess file in app-root, but it seems no file can be saved there.

Comment: No one here can guess your installation's directory structure.  Don't you know where you uploaded or installed Drupal?  Perhaps searching with a command like `find / -name index.php` might point you in the right direction, but it could take a while to run.

Comment: I used drupal quickstart and the openshift file structure is quite complex and unconventional compared to traditional hostings I am used to. I found one .htaccess file and edited the question now.

Comment: Then you should look for it elsewhere as it would make no sense to install a program or website inside a download directory, wouldn't it?